# textFieldDidEndEditing not firing when pickerviiew used in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, uitextfield, uipickerview

The text field delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing` is not firing when picker view is used in Swift 3. How can I call it? There is no button to dynamically call the delegate.

You can see my code below.

[image: image here]

```
import UIKit

class ThroewViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var pickerText: UITextField!


    let thePicker = UIPickerView()
    var dashTitle_Arr = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerText.delegate = self
       thePicker.dataSource = self
        thePicker.delegate = self
       pickerText.inputView = thePicker



    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return dashTitle_Arr .count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {


        return dashTitle_Arr [row]     }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


        pickerText.text = dashTitle_Arr [row]

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        addIntoArray(text: textField.text)
    }

    func addIntoArray(text: String?) {

        guard let text = text, text.characters.count > 0 else {

            return
        }

        dashTitle_Arr.append(text)
        thePicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

Comment: in didSelectRow delegate method , you can forcefully end the editing of textField , just add the one line in that method : pickerText.resignFirstResponder .

Comment: actually I need to append the string to the array object that needs to save in that array but it not working

Comment: you have to put that line after pickerText.text = dashTitle_Arr [row] this line . still not working ? let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property of `picker-view` is `accessoriesView`. Create a `tool bar` with `done` or `cancel` button and set it in the picker view's `assessoriesView`.

In the toolbar `button` `action` write the `textfield.resignFirstResponder()`
After that the `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate method fired

It works fine for me. Hope it will helps you. Thank you